# How do I set COM file details (e.g. sendername or date received) on a file with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, com

I know how to get the file details using a call to `GetDetailsOf` through the `Shell.Application` COM object and passing the corresponding index (between 1 - 266). But I can't figure out how to set one of those on a new file.

Comment: from what i can tell, those are only set with the app that set them IN THE FILE. those are extended file attributes and are only readable by the filesystem when there is an installed extension for that file type. if you look at several different systems where apps were installed in different orders ... you will find that some of the ID numbers can be very different. [*grin*]

Comment: The shell itself doesn't expose a way to change properties of a shell item (except the name, which you can change using `Shell.Application`). One way is (in C++) to use an `IShellItem`, then `IShellItem::BindToHandler` with `BHID_PropertyStore` and use `IPropertyStore:SetValue` (note Shell.Application exposes the `GetValue` through `ShellFolderItem.ExtendedProperty`, but not the `SetValue`...), but even with that not all folders support changing properties.